# Error in Rails with JS code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails will not let me run JS code, I have these errors

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

whenever you add JS code, the errors appear.
Some idea why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're getting error highlights in your IDE, doesn't necessarily mean your code is wrong. Try running your server, navigate to your site from your browser, and check the developer console. Do you still see javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

This warning (it is not an error) is being displayed because your IDE thinks that the variable `$` is not defined in your code. However, it is not able to find out that `$` is a global variable defined in the jQuery library, imported a few lines before.

The IDE is just saying that the presence of that variable is not guaranteed unless you properly import the needed libraries to make it exist (jQuery in this case). Your code should work properly. In order to identify errors in your javascript code, I would recommend you to use the built in console in the web browser.